# Highlighting keywords beginning with colon in Vim

Tags: vim, vim-syntax-highlighting

I wrote a vim syntax file. I notice that all keywords except those beginning with a colon (`:`) are being highlighted. Is there any way to *escape* colons in Vim?

Here's a section of the file:

```
syn keyword actionLabel :action nextgroup=actionName skipwhite
syn keyword problemLabels :goal :init :domain
syn keyword advLabels :types
syn keyword pondLabels :observe


hi def link actionLabel     Statement
hi def link problemLabels   Statement
hi def link advLabels       Statement
hi def link pondLabels      Statement
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From `:h :syn-define` about keywords...

> It can only contain keyword characters, according to the
>   '**iskeyword**'    option.  It cannot contain other syntax items.  It will
>   only match with a    complete word (there are no keyword characters
>   before or after the match).    The keyword "if" would match in
>   "if(a=b)", but not in "ifdef x", because    "(" is not a keyword
>   character and "d" is.

That means you'll have to modify [iskeyword](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27iskeyword%27) for your file type to include the colon character (ascii 58).  Starting from the vi default, we can support any alphabetic character, number, underscore, or colon:

```
set iskeyword="@,48-58,_"
```

Answer (score 4):

The best solution seems to be not using the `keyword` option, but using the `matches` option instead.

```
syn match pddlLabel ':[a-zA-Z0-9]\+'
hi def link pddlLabel Statement
```

Comment: That will match *anything* starting with a colon, not just specific keywords.  That might be what you want, but it's important to be aware of.

Comment: Yes, I understand. It's more or less what I want. I can also write 1 of these statements for each explicit keyword, although that's time consuming, I admit. `syn matches pddlLabel1 ':action'` etc.